# AEM login screen is not apprearing in a linux machine AEM6.3

Tags: aem

I have set up AEM 6.3 on remote Linux machine. But when I try to access the AEM from browser, it says "Connection has timed out".

I am not getting any error in the **error.log** file. Also, in **stdout.log** file, it says "**Startup completed**".

Also, I checked that port(`4502`) is not blocked on the server.

When I put command "`curl http://localhost:4502/`" on the server, I am not getting any error, which makes me assume that the connection is established.

Do I need to do any other configuration or something in order to access it from the browser? I am using `http://ip:4502/` in the browser..

Comment: Ping the server. If that responds, then telnet the port. One of these should point to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly a firewall issue, check and check again :)

Look in the AEM Access log (same folder as the other logs you looked in) can you see any requests coming in from your browser? There is no other config required on AEM to access other than starting it up, assuming there is nothing network/firewall related blocking then you should be able to access it.

Comment: No, I don't see anything in the access.log. (0 KB)

Comment: That means your request has not even made it to AEM so there must be some firewall/network problem getting in the way